# How to add one to the value of the record based on the previous record

Tags: mysql

Hypothetically,In the table which had 1000 records，but there are one column(Digital type) without value,just like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aupSH.png)

then I want to update table like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6zM3.png)

I hope you give me some advice,appreciate greatly!

Comment: is columns type integer or string ?

Comment: it's String type @zey

Comment: have you try like this ? `ALTER TABLE your_table_name MODIFY COLUMN INDICATRIX_CODE  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001`

Comment: @zey  I understand your meanings,This was what i had thought about. If i try to do this,Then the previous 1000 records will be null, this operation is effective for the later.thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, even if it is a string field, assuming you want to insert a number as in the picture you can use the following example for reference:

```
DROP TABLE test_table;

CREATE TABLE test_table
    (`col_1` varchar(10), `col_2` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO test_table
    (`col_1`, `col_2`)
VALUES
    ('A', null),
    ('B', null),
    ('C', null),
    ('D', null),
    ('E', null)
;
```

and then query to the update the null col_2

```
SET @new_value := 999;

update test_table set col_2 = @new_value:=@new_value + 1;

select * from test_table;
```

Basically I define the new value to be 1 minus my start (1000 -1 = 999) with `SET @new_value := 999;` and then during the update I set @new_value to be equal to itself + 1 which then set to col_2.  The update continues onto the next row which then sets to 1000 + 1, and so on.

Comment: thanks for answer,This is what i want . appreciate deeply!